# bruteforce with Xillinx FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, xilinx

How can I brute force a password list with xillinx FPGAs?
For example, I have a zip file that encrypted with password, I want to check password list with high speed to open this zip file. i want to use FPGA for this kind of purpose.
Is there any verilog or VHDL code that configurable to brute force ?
Is there any documents to help me to use FPGA in this field?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by brute force password list?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: The problem isn't the brute forcing or the password list. You need to identify the source code that handles password access to zip files, and port that algorithm to VHDL (or Verilog). Get it working in simulation with your own zipfile where you know the password, and then you can think about brute forcing from there.

Comment: Why do you think it will be faster with a FPGA vs a high-end Pentium? Also, do you have an idea of the complexity of this project, or is it just a random idea?

Comment: How many files do you need to crack? Is this something you expect to do repeatedly? If so, how often?

Comment: This is not random idea. i want to crack one zip file for example.
I want to know how this procedure going on.

Comment: If you only need to do it once, there are software applications specifically designed to crack zip files. It would not be worth it to invest in an asic, I don't think. If you need to crack many files as fast as possibly, it could be worth while to look into hardware acceleration. But the place to start is reading the source code of a cracker, or learning more about how the zip file is encrypted. You can check out "jack the ripper" for example. Just type that in google.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with an FPGA?

Answer (score 2):

The problem of brute-force password cracking is not the amount of passwords you can generate. It's the speed of the API you need to use to enter the password and the service behind it to validate your input.

So for a zip file, you could implement the zip-file password validation algorithm in an FPGA (very hard work - especially for a beginner) and then let an FPGA do thousands of tries per second. If the algorithm doesn't take to much space on your FPGA, you could create multiple instances of your brute-force design.

Multiple instances require coordination, so each instance will run on a unique set of inputs. Or you could decide to use different approaches: linear (brute-force), random, dictionary, ...

Comment: Thanks my friend. 
How can i develop this code, you are mentioned it.
Where i should to begin?
Do you have any documents  can guide me?

Comment: I think with FPGA i can do this faster.